# How to insert values to table that are there only in the JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I've a table which is created with below SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE example (
       col1 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
       col2 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
       col3 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

I want to insert values to this table from a JSON object. JSON object is constructed such way that its key is the column name and value is the value to be inserted.

How do I write a PHP code to only insert the values that are there in the JSON object?

For instance, If I have a JSON object

```
{
     "col1": "some value",
     "col3": "some value"
}
```

The insert statement should only insert values to col1 and col3 and the col2 should remain as NULL.

Please help me out to solve this puzzle. PHP with PDO is preferable.

**Experiments performed so far**

```
$object = json_decode($jsonObject);

foreach ($object as $col => $val) {
       $columns .= $col . ",";
       $values .= $val . ",";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO example (" .substr($columns, 0, strlen($columns)-2) .
       ") VALUES (" . substr($values, 0, strlen($columns)-2) . ")";
```

Comment: You making some attempt first is preferable.

Comment: I did. I'll post the code in a moment

Comment: Is `col2` changing from `null` when you do an `insert` statement? If so what does it change to?

Comment: As my question indicate I'm trying to find the insert statement created using PHP. from the JSON object.

Comment: You need to use `json_decode($jsonObject, true)` to get an array instead of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty close. The problem is that you don't have quotes around each value in `$values`.

Here's another way to write it:

```
$object = json_decode($jsonObject, true);
$columns = implode(', ', array_keys($object);
$values = implode(', ', array_map(function($x) { return "'$x'"; }, $object));

$sql = "INSERT INTO example($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

The function in `array_map()` returns each value with quotes around it, then `implode()` combines them all with commas.

If you're using PDO, you can pass an array of values to `PDOStatement::execute()`.

```
$values = array_values($object);
// Create "?, ?, ?, ..." string with enough placeholders for the values
$placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO example($columns) VALUES ($placeholders)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute($values);
```

Comment: A small concern though, This insert statement is open to SQL injection, right? How do I solve this using bindParam() of PDO?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to pass an array of values to execute.

Comment: I hope you are aware of the fact that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You mean the column names? Other than validating them, there's no good way around that, since you can't use placeholders for that.

Comment: So you are. Noted.

Comment: Yup I did. 1 minute ahead of you :-)

Comment: @Barmar, No need to validate the column in my case. The JSON is coming from an Android App.

Comment: @SamuelRobert If it's coming from a client machine, the user can modify it before it's sent, so you should validate.

Comment: Sure I'll. A small doubt, How do I convert the JSON object to "key1=value1, key2=value2, ... keyN=valueN"? This is for the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Part of the insert query.

Comment: You can create an array containing `keyN = VALUES(keyN)` from `$columns`, then use `implode()` to concatenate them into a string, and append that to the query.